# polymer 1.0 dom-repeat filter only runs once

Tags: polymer

When I change the year using the drop-down, I want the list to re-filter and display the info for that chosen year. What am I missing? Changing the year does not re-filter the dom-repeat.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="http://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
  <title>dropdown</title>
  <link rel="import" href="http://polygit.org/components/paper-menu/paper-menu.html">
  <link rel="import" href="http://polygit.org/components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
  <link rel="import" href="http://polygit.org/components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
  <link rel="import" href="http://polygit.org/components/paper-menu-button/paper-menu-button.html">
  <style>
    .taller{
      height:120px;
    }
    [vertical-align="top"] ul {
      margin-top: 0;
    }
    [vertical-align="bottom"] ul {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    button, paper-button {
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      background-color: #eee;
      /*padding: 1em;*/
      border-radius: 3px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    button:focus {
      outline: none;
      border-color: blue;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <dom-module id="x-demo">
    <template>
    <div class="horizontal-section flex layout horizontal taller">
      <paper-menu-button>
        <paper-button icon="menu" class="dropdown-trigger"><span>Year<br/></span><span>{{year}}</span></paper-button>
        <paper-menu id="selectedYear" class="dropdown-content" selected="{{selectedIndex}}">
          <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{allData}}">
            <paper-item on-tap='yearTapped'>{{item.year}}</paper-item>
          </template>
        </paper-menu>
      </paper-menu-button>
      <paper-menu-button>
        <paper-button icon="menu" class="dropdown-trigger"><span>Make<br/></span><span>{{make}}</span></paper-button>
        <paper-menu id="selectedMake" class="dropdown-content" selected="{{selectedIndex}}">
          <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{allData}}">
            <paper-item on-tap='makeTapped'>{{item.make}}</paper-item>
          </template>
        </paper-menu>
      </paper-menu-button>
      <paper-menu-button>
        <paper-button icon="menu" class="dropdown-trigger"><span>Model<br/></span><span>{{model}}</span></paper-button>
        <paper-menu id="selectedModel" class="dropdown-content" selected="{{selectedIndex}}">
          <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{allData}}">
            <paper-item on-tap='modelTapped'>{{item.model}}</paper-item>
          </template>
        </paper-menu>
      </paper-menu-button>
      <paper-menu-button>
        <paper-button icon="menu" class="dropdown-trigger"><span>Engine<br/></span><span>{{engine}}</span></paper-button>
        <paper-menu id="selectedEngine" class="dropdown-content" selected="{{selectedIndex}}">
          <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{allData}}">
            <paper-item on-tap='engineTapped'>{{item.engine}}</paper-item>
          </template>
        </paper-menu>
      </paper-menu-button>
    </div>
    <div>Vehicle list filtered by selected year: </div>
    <template is="dom-repeat" id="vehicleList" items="{{allData}}" filter="yearMatch" observe="year item.year">
        <div>Year <span>{{item.year}}</span></div>
        <div>Make <span>{{item.make}}</span></div>
        <div>Model <span>{{item.model}}</span></div>
        <div>Engine <span>{{item.engine}}</span></div>
        <button on-click="toggleSelection">Select</button>
    </template>
    <array-selector id="selector" items="{{allData}}" selected="{{selected}}" multi toggle></array-selector>
    <div>Selected vehicle: </div>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{selected}}">
        <div><span>{{item.year}}</span></div>
        <div><span>{{item.make}}</span></div>
        <div><span>{{item.model}}</span></div>
        <div><span>{{item.engine}}</span></div>
    </template>

    </template>
    <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'x-demo',
      properties:{
        allData:{type:Array,
          value: function() {
          return [{year:'2015',make:'HONDA',model:'CB300F',engine:'300cc'},
                  {year:'2014',make:'HONDA',model:'CBR300R',engine:'300cc'}];
          }         
        },
        year:{type:String,value:'2014',notify:true}
      },
    observers: [
      'yearChanged(year)'
    ],
    yearChanged: function(item) {
      console.log(item);
      this.set('item.year', item);
      this.$.vehicleList.render();
    },
    yearMatch: function(item) {
        console.log('year checked');
        return item.year = this.year;
      },
    toggleSelection: function(e) {
        var item = this.$.vehicleList.itemForElement(e.target);
        this.$.selector.select(item);
      },
    yearTapped: function(e) {
      this.year=e.target.innerText;
    },
    makeTapped: function(e) {
      this.make=e.target.innerText;
    },
    modelTapped: function(e) {
      this.model=e.target.innerText;
    },
    engineTapped: function(e) {
      this.engine=e.target.innerText;
    }
    });
  </script>
  </dom-module>
  <x-demo></x-demo>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The jsbin has a slight glitch where the dropdown is invisible, but is still clickable. http://jsbin.com/foqala/4/edit?html,output

Comment: I have similar question, but it is just because I don't have the "this.$.vehicleList.render();" in my code. Thanks for your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works for me

```
 <script>
HTMLImports.whenReady(function () {
    Polymer({
        is: 'x-demo',
        properties:{
            allData:{
                type:Array,
                value: [{
                    year:'2015',
                    make:'HONDA',
                    model:'CB300F',
                    engine:'300cc'
                }, {
                    year:'2014',
                    make:'HONDA',
                    model:'CBR300R',
                    engine:'300cc'
                }]        
            },
            year:{
                type:
                String,
                value:'2014',
                observer: 'yearChanged'    
            }
        },
        yearChanged: function() {
            console.log(this.year)
          this.$.vehicleList.render();
        },
        yearMatch: function(item) {
            return item.year == this.year;
         },
        toggleSelection: function(e) {
            var item = this.$.vehicleList.itemForElement(e.target);
            this.$.selector.select(item);
          },
        yearTapped: function(event) {
            var res = event.target.innerText || event.target.textContent;
            this.year = res.replace(/\s+/g, '');
        },
        makeTapped: function(event) {
            var res =  event.target.innerText || event.target.textContent;
            this.make = res.replace(/\s+/g, '');
        },
        modelTapped: function(event) {
            var res =  event.target.innerText || event.target.textContent;
            this.model = res.replace(/\s+/g, '');
        },
        engineTapped: function(event) {
            var res =  event.target.innerText || event.target.textContent;
            this.engine = res.replace(/\s+/g, '');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! All I needed was a double equals instead of a single here: return item.year == this.year;

Comment: but dont forget that firefox doesnt know the innerText property and return undefined